# Lua table/list string cast/concat

Tags: string, lua, concatenation

Is there any method more efficient but simpler as the *anonymous function* use, when casting a list (*A table with only one level*) to string?

Why asking this? I Have heard that the string concatenation over and over in Lua is **memory inefficient** because Lua strings are immutable objects that have to be thrown to the garbage collector once used.

So with **anonymous function usage** I mean this:

```lua
local resources = {
    ["bread"] = 20,
    ["meat"] = 5,
    ["something"] = 99
};

local function getTheText()
    return "Resources:\n"..
        ( (function()
             local s = "";
             for k, v in pairs(resources) do
                 s = s.."\n\t"..k..": "..v.." units.";
             end
             return s;
        )())..
        "\nMore awesome info...";
   end
end
```

You know, for this time I could use **a metafunction** like a *tostring* on this table because it is not going to change, but if I use other **anonymous tables** I will not have this option.

Anyway I love the anonymous usage of functions so, it is not a problem for me.

---

Is there anything more efficient that does **not** require declaring functions? and is this more or less efficient than using a metamethod?

Comment: How is your "anonymous function" relevant? It just adds a closure creation and a function call.

Comment: Not at all in fact for the "Memory consumptiom problem", just is something that I wanted to point out because sometimes I need to concatenate "inline" and do not reuse the function. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
local function getTheText()
    local temp = {"Resources:"}
    for k,v in pairs(resources) do
        temp[#temp + 1] = "\t"..k..": "..v.." units."
     end
     temp[#temp + 1] = "More Awesome info..."
     return table.concat(temp, "\n")
end
```

`table.concat` will build strings efficiently and use less memory than concatenating via `s = s ..`.

This issue is covered in [PIL](http://www.lua.org/pil/11.6.html)

Comment: Thanks! This is very userfull! (Didn't know/remember about the **table.concat**). Sometimes I don't know what is more efficient because of the language shifting (When I use Java, then Lua or something like this). Very appreciated!